# What should i include to prevent the popup error shown in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, eclipse

[image]

I have created these 4 boxes description. If I didn't key in anything for all the boxes, an error message will appear. However, I want an additional function where if I only key in information for the arm (arm exercise and no. of times), I still can submit.

I created an if else function but it shows an error when I key in only the first two box and the other two boxes are blank.

> For input string : " "

this is my string sql.

> String sql="Insert into exercise(Arm, Time1, Leg, Time2)
>   Values(?,?,?,?)";

edited:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRzLA.png)

Comment: Show us code and the table's schema.

Comment: Which part of my code would you want to see?